# List Filtering performance issue in wpf C# Viewmodel

Tags: c#, performance

I came across a performance issues when doing normal list filtering using FirstOrDefault. I am getting the data from the server in <2ms but the filtering takes 15,252 ms.This looks strange to me and  I will be glad if someone could help me on this.

Here is the method and this line `Loginaccess = loginlist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LogName == LogTitle);` takes 15,252 ms to execute.

```
private void GetData()
        {
            LoginServices obj = new LoginServices();
            loginlist = obj.getlogins();
            Loginaccess = loginlist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LogName == LogTitle);
        }
```

Here is how the list and Entity type is declared

```
 public List<LoginEntity> loginlist
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private LoginEntity _loginaccess;
    public LoginEntity Loginaccess
    {
        get { return _loginaccess; }
        set
        {
            _loginaccess = value;

        }
    }
```

Comment: _"I am getting the data from the server in <2ms"_ I assume that `getlogins` just returns the query and `FirstOrDefault` will actually execute it. That's called deferred execution.

Comment: How many items are in your loginlist?  It does seem a long time for the query, but processing time depends on so many things, and this is obviously the most pertinent.  Can you perform some testing by querying for the first item in the list and the final item in the list, and that will give you some useful characteristics about how long it really takes to search.  But if it does just take that long then you'll have to work out a better way of accessing, e.g. using a hashset and providing the login name as the has if that is unique/possible

Comment: @TimSchmelter No `getlogins` gets the data and it holds only 3 records.

Comment: @LordWilmore `loginlist` holds only 3 items

Comment: Why my questions get marked by -1 whenever i post to Stackoverflow, This is disheartening. I always first search everywhere before using this board.

Comment: @SamKing: show `getlogins`. Is it really `15252` milliseconds or `15.252`(depends on your decimal separator).

Comment: @TimSchmelter its a service method and its gets data from web server which is is <2ms . I couldn't post the code of getlogins as it was above the character limit

Comment: Is the `LoginService` delivering dummy data? 2ms is pretty fast.

And does the query takes different time when you have a match or not?

Comment: @OlafW its returning correct data, Yes there is a difference if no data is returned. i tried with various methods like using tolookup, asparallel and dictionary. so where the predicates are put the execution takes lot of time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if the login is found or not. If you've got 4 records and the `LogTitle` is found or not?

Comment: @OlafW Yes its found. I think i found the issue. this is because i am trying to get the LogTitle like this  `public string LogTitle
        {
            get { return System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName; }
        }` so everytime predicates tries to match with logtitle  this line is getting executed.

Comment: This could be a reason - so just create a copy or refactor your `LogTitle` to:

`private string _LogTitle;
public string LogTitle { get { if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(_LogTitle) {
_LogTitle = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;} 
return _LogTitle;
}`